# Location of Language and Locale files

Tags: opensuse, locale, glibc

I'm using OpenSUSE 13.2 with GNOME 3.14 Desktop Environment.
My interface language is en_US while my locale is ar_SY.
My locale contain some wrong data about months names (May and June) and I want to repair that manually.
Where can I find the locale files in order to change the values?
Not the locale but the data with in the locale, for instance:
In Syria, May is `أيار` but it's written as `نواران` in the locale ar_SY and I want to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale files are located probably under `/usr/share/locale/*/LC_MESSAGES'` in your system, but those are in a binary format.

Their actual sources (in a editable, human-readable format) are not usually shipped with your distro. In this case, you'll have to search for them in upstream.

In your specific case, try searching for the translation you want to fix in https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps, and maybe submit a pull request for them.

Comment: I suspect that the locale maintainers would like to know that there are errors in their data so that it can be fixed for everyone.

Comment: In fact, that was what I suggested: submitting a pull request would make everyone benefit from any potential errors.

Comment: I did contact the locale maintainer, the Arab Eyes team, but with no response.

Answer (score 3):

I did found the locale files but not were @thiagowfx pointed. They are in `/usr/lib/locale/`, and they belong to one `glibc-locale` package. I downloaded the source package and corrected the locale for ar_SY, and now I don't know how to compile and install my modified version of package!

Comment: [`man localedef`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/localedef)

Comment: `localedef --help` outputs the directory path of the binary locale database near the bottom, paired with the source location; e.g. `locale path    : /usr/lib/locale:/usr/share/i18n`